# if only can I block the green nav (use the `{% block %}`), then can get the effect?

Tags: django, django-templates

You see the green nav is a div, on it there are several items.

Now all the templates contains the green nav.

When the page is `index/`, the first item is selected, when the page is `productlist/` the second item is selected. realize the effect is by css(like `<li class="on"><a href="/index/" name="index">网站首页</a></li>`).

[image]

Now, if only can I block the green nav (use the `{% block %}`), then can get the effect?  If do not use the block, if should every template contains the green nav code?

If there is a better method to reduce the code amount?

Comment: yeah, you can use block..

Comment: @AvinashRaj If I use the block, every template will write as much as the before codes. I means use the block will write almost same amount codes. is there a better method to reduce code amount?

Comment: If the amount of code is huge you can divide the code in other template partials and import it using the {% include 'partial.html' %} tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do this:

- Have the nav menu in your parent template (so each template `extends` the parent template with the nav menu). If you add a context variable such as `{'active_menu': 'index'}` to your template rendering, then it's available in your parent template and you can check the value to decide which menu item should get the class `on`.
- Or you can just `{% include 'nav.html' with active_menu='index' %}` in each template, setting the variable `active_menu` right there in the template.

In both cases you use `{% if active_menu=='index' %}` conditional tag to set the class on the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't reccommend using a block for this purpose, instead use a variable in your context:

```
def index(request):
  #your code
  context = {
      "selected_nav": "index",
      #your other stuff
  }
  return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

And in your nav template:

```
<li class="{% if selected_nav == 'index' %}on{% endif %}"><a href="/index/" name="index">网站首页</a></li>
```

Another option would would be to set the selected_nav variable in the template wherever you include the navbar, this is only if you do include it in every template though:

```
{% include 'navbar_template.html' with selected_navbar='index' %}
```